# Maven install in jekins job doesn't failed because of tee command

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, tee

I am using Jenkinsfile to build a maven project.
To save the build logs I am running:

```
mvn install | tee  > log.txt
```

But because of the `tee` command, Jenkins is unable to catch if **mvn install** or the build step is failing or not.

I tried to run:

```
mvn install | tee > log.txt 2>&1
```

and

```
mvn install 2>&1 | tee > log.txt
```

but it didn't worked.

Comment: If you are running on Jenkins why are you trying to capture the log file? Jenkins already does that? Apart from that why do you use `mvn install` on Jenkins?

Comment: I need it for next steps inside the build. And why not to use mvn install? not sure I understated your question

Comment: What kind of next steps is the log file needed? Install is usually not needed....Why are you doing the install instead of `mvn clean verify` ?

Comment: I have some steps that require the log file, and the jar files that create in the mvn install.

Comment: You are repeating things. You wrote already that you have supplemental steps but you haven't told what these steps are and why?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I find that what worked for me is to run `mvn install` from external file (.sh), and add `test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0` in the end of my cmd:

```
mvn clean install | tee log.txt ; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0
```

It worked wall, saved the mvn log and failed the build is there was any error droning the the `mvn install` cmd